# Split string with commas while keeping numeric parts

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, function

I'm using the following function to separate strings with commas right on the capitals, as long as it is not preceded by a blank space.

def func(x):

```
y = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+(?:\s+\S[^A-Z\s]*)*', x)

return ','.join(y)
```

However, when I try to separate the next string it removes the part with numbers.

Input = '49ersRiders Mapple'

Output = 'Riders Mapple'

I tried the following code but now it removes the 'ers' part.

def test(x):

```
y = re.findall(r'\d+[A-Z]*|[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+(?:\s+\S[^A-Z\s]*)*', x)

return ','.join(y)
```

Output = '49,Riders Mapple'

The output I'm looking for is this:

'49ers,Riders Mapple'

Is it possible to add this indication to my regex?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe naive but why don't you use `re.sub`:

```
def func(x):
    return re.sub(r'(?<!\s)([A-Z])', r',\1', x)

inp = '49ersRiders Mapple'
out = func(inp)
print(out)

# Output
49ers,Riders Mapple
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex `re.findall` approach:

```py
inp = "49ersRiders"
output = ','.join(re.findall('(?:[A-Z]|[0-9])[^A-Z]+', inp))
print(output)  # 49ers,Riders
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
(?:
    [A-Z]  a leading uppercase letter (try to find this first)
    |      OR
    [0-9]  a leading number (fallback for no uppercase)
)
[^A-Z]+    one or more non capital letters following
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, It gave me a better undestanding of regex. I didn't explain myself correctly in the question but found the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I think you could also write it without the non capture group in this case `[A-Z0-9][^A-Z]+`